# Unzipping a Zip File in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to unzip a zip file in Django using the `zipfile` library.

This is my code:

```
if formtoaddmodel.is_valid():
        content = request.FILES['content']
        unzipped = zipfile.ZipFile(content)
        print unzipped.namelist()
        for libitem in unzipped.namelist():
            filecontent = file(libitem,'wb').write(unzipped.read(libitem))
```

This is the output of `print unzipped.namelist()`

```
['FileName1.jpg', 'FileName2.png', '__MACOSX/', '__MACOSX/._FileName2.png']
```

Im wondering what the last two items are -- it looks like the path. I don't care about there -- so how is there a way to filter them out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder

```
if libitem.startswith('__MACOSX/'):
  continue
```

Answer (score 2):

Those files are tags added by the zip utility on MACS. You can assume the name starts with '__MACOSX/'

[link](http://floatingsun.net/2007/02/07/whats-with-__macosx-in-zip-files/)